# AmplifyS3ImagePicker component of @aws-amplify/ui-react

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I wanted to use AmplifyS3ImagePicker component in a React application.
Unable to find any callback method on AmplifyS3ImagePicker component.

The [AmplifyS3ImagePicker](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/storage/s3-image-picker/q/framework/react) documentation has no mention about the callback methods such that,
image load status, progress status etc...

Anybody used AmplifyS3ImagePicker in React project.

Comment: AwsImagePicker component is the right component to use. The selected image should be uploaded with Storage.put as defined at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/browser-based-uploads-aws-amplify.html